# Transition not working properly with rgba

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I have a project here in which I want an overlay to come on top of a picture when you click on a link so that we can read some information about a product. The effect I am looking for is something like this:

[image]

In order to do this I have a div with the info and a white background inside the div that has the picture, like so:

```
      <div id="leftWindow">
        <a href="notalink.html" id="infoButton">+ Information</a>
        <div id="info" class="notVisible">
          Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product
        </div>
      </div>
```

the div with the info has a class of "notVisible" and I have another class that has a an opacity of .7, like so:

```
#info {
    background-color: white;
    transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 342px;
    height: 516px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.visibleIsh {
    opacity: .7;
}
```

When you click on the link, some javascript swaps the classes:

```
$( document ).on('click', '#infoButton', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#info").removeClass("notVisible").addClass("visibleIsh");

});
```

This works, but the problem is that the text also looses opacity which I don't want. To solve this, I use rgba instead of opacity, like so:

css:

```
.visibleIsh {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}

#info {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    transition: background-color 1.5s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 342px;
    height: 516px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

[image]

And I get the buggy behaviour you can see in the gif. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything buggy in the 2nd gif. Please explain the issue.

Comment: there is no smooth transition and no .7 applied on the alpha

Comment: If I remember correctly, you cannot apply a fade transition directly to text - it wont transition, but rather just disappear all at once when the transition times out. You have to fade the container holding the text instead.

Comment: I think the issue is with your `notVisible` class. Can you please provide your **full** code, as this fiddle (isolating only problem in question - transition) seems to do what you're after: https://jsfiddle.net/hh0cjkwf/1/ . Is there changing of `display: none` to `display: block` by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Currently what you're doing is just fading the background color. The text would be visible at all times using that approach. If you want it to look like your first gif, you should just set the background opacity at .7 to begin with and hide the entire `#info` element. Then you could use jQuery to fade the entire element in on click.

```js
$( document ).on('click', '#infoButton', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#info").fadeIn(1500);

});
```

```css
#info {
    display:none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 342px;
    height: 516px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="leftWindow">
 <a href="notalink.html" id="infoButton">+ Information</a>
 <div id="info">Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product
 </div>
</div>
```

Alright, let's assume that @eithed is correct in their assumption and you want to do this with a CSS class rather than jQuery. You could also accomplish it like this (the `z-index` property is important because `opacity` does not hide the element from the DOM, so without it, you would not be able to click the `+ Information` link as the `#info` element would be covering it):

```js
$( document ).on('click', '#infoButton', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#info").addClass('visible');
});
```

```css
#info {
    opacity:0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 342px;
    height: 516px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    transition:all 1.5s;
    z-index:-1;
}
  #info.visible {
    opacity:1;
    z-index:10;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="leftWindow">
 <a href="notalink.html" id="infoButton">+ Information</a>
 <div id="info">Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product Some information about this product
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to do the transition using CSS, rather than JS

Comment: They never specified that, and they're already using JS anyway. Additionally, the question is tagged with `Javascript` and `jQuery`.

Comment: Seeing that they're using the transition within the CSS one can assume

Comment: You know what they say about assuming.